# How to force UTF-8 encoding when extracting a link using RSelenium?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, rselenium

I'm using RSelenium to run a RemoteDriver on my system. I need to extract a link from a page, and read that link with UTF-8 encoding (so that I can convert it to the encoding I need). 
This is what I'm doing right now -

`url <- paste0("https://www.google.co.in/#q=abc+xyz")
remDr$navigate(url)
x <- remDr$findElement("css","._tWc")$getElementAttribute("href")`

However, here the encoding of x is unknown (using `Encoding(x)`). Is there any way I can extract the link, while preserving the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Scraping google is against their ToS

Comment: You are completely free to have that opinion. People are wrong all the time.